# OneSignal issues when I try integrate SDK in Android Studio 2

Tags: android, gradle, push-notification, onesignal

I followed this documentation about how integrate
[OneSignal for Android Studio](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-studio-sdk-installation) but without success.

When I try to add the compile dependencies to build.gradle (Module) file

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
```

I also add in build.gradle file the manifestPlaceholders with the correct key.

In addition, I develop my application with java8 feature and I must enable jackOption like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "eu.application.test"
    manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                            onesignal_app_id: "PUT YOUR ONESIGNAL APP ID HERE",
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "PUT YOUR GOOGLE PROJECT NUMBER HERE"]
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

The Android Studio version is 2.1.3 and I have java 1.8.0_25. 
Android Studio can install the app but with a lot of effort and a lot of time (about 10 minutes) and sometimes I must restart my computer.

Comment: put your device log here

Comment: There isn't device log, start "gradle build running" and the application does not installed

Comment: me sure your manifest luncher activity is defined or not ?

Comment: the AndroidManifest is deined with all permiossione like as https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/installing-the-onesignal-android-sdk

Comment: After long process.. This is the error.Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Timeout waiting to lock daemon addresses registry. It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: 8036
Our PID: 8711
Owner Operation: 
Our operation: 
Lock file: /Users/blake/.gradle/daemon/2.14.1/registry.bin.lock

Comment: which is your default class?

Comment: There is a default activity that is launched at the start

Comment: but  you not defined that in manifest

Comment: My manifest is like this https://gist.github.com/luli-isa/d938bd4d8120687e45f2dac109dfe506

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `.grandle` entries from

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
```

TO:

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0"
```

The 3.+ ensures you have the latest OneSignal stable build. analytics isn't needed by OneSignal if you are using gcm 8.1.0 or newer.

Remove any `AndroidManifest.xml` you have added from the [OneSignal Eclipse](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/installing-the-onesignal-android-sdk) documentation as it will interfere with the Android Studio setup.

Since you are experiencing system slow downs I recommend trying out our tested example project to eliminate other variables.
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/tree/master/Examples/AndroidStudio